# super().__init__(damage) Undefined Variable

Tags: python-3.x

i have a problem with the utilisation of `super().__init__(damage)` i have undefined variable on damage, i have read de documentation and i think im ok with the syntaxe
i have test : `Weapon().__init__(self, damage)` and its the same problem

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, damage):

        self.damage = damage
        

    def generateItemStats(self):

        self.damage = random.randint(1, 5)



class Item(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, quality):
        super().__init__(damage) #error here undefined variable damage

        self.quality = quality
        self.generateQuality()

    def generateQuality(self):

        #self.quality = 500
        self.quality = random.randint(0, 500)

    def generateItem(self):

        if self.quality <= 300:
            print("Normal")
        elif self.quality > 300 and self.quality <= 450:
            print("Magique")
        elif self.quality > 450 and self.quality <= 499:
            print("Rare")
        else:
            print("Légendaire")


item1 = Item("")
item1.generateItem()
```

i have import random at the start :)

Comment: Please provide your entire error report in your question.  The report should be encapsulated in ``` before and after `` to ensure it appears as code.

Comment: The reason is that the variable `damage` that you pass to the super is not an argument of `Item`, the only arguments you provide to the class is `quality`. In order for the code to work you have to provide the extra argument `damage`, in any case use `def __init__(self, quality, damage)` and all it using `Item('', 0)`. Alternatively you can provide a default value if you do not pass damage, (use `def __init__(self, quality, damage=0)`, now you can call it using `Item('')` and `damage` will be `0`, or `Item('', 5)` and `damage` will be `5`, where 5 is an arbitrary value.

Comment: It's weird that `Item` inherits from `Weapon`. It should be the other way around: a weapon is an item but an item is not necessarily a weapon.  If you see items and weapons as sets, then the set of weapons is a subset of the set of items. Conclusion: `Weapon` is a subclass of `Item`.